# How to simplify identical events in multiple Outlook calendars?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, google-calendar

The simplest case of the problem is a work calendar and a personal/family calendar that have some events in common, but not all. I want to see both calendars at the same time, but not the multiple copies of the events that they share in common.

One ostensible solution is to simply share the personal calendar so that I can see it while I'm using Outlook at work. This works for some things, but not for situations in which the event needs to impact both calendars. For example, a dr's appointment. I want to block the time on both calendars so that I don't get meetings scheduled during that time at work, and so that the other users of the family calendar can see that event, too. Unless the work account and the personal account are both actually attendees of the event, then the event won't provide conflict detection.

The problem with having both accounts as attendees of the same event is that the event appears on the calendar twice. Another problem with this is showing all of my coworkers who are also attending such-and-such a meeting, my personal email account that I've added as an attendee, so that it'll show up on my personal calendar.

This is a minor inconvenience for two calendars, but I'm now in a situation where I have 6 separate calendars that all need to block time for similar events. Now I have 6 copies of the same events showing up on my calendar.

Another ostensible solution is to just hide the additional calendars, so their copies don't show up. But this will also hide any events that are unique to that calendar (which is not a few, in my case). I don't want to hide unique events because they're useful to see, even if I don't want them blocking time out of my work calendar.

So, I would like to have visibility into all of my calendars at once, while collapsing/simplifying/hiding any events that are identical on more than one calendar. Also without having to share my personal account with coworkers, let alone all of the other non-work attendees who might also be on the event.

Is there a feature, plugin, or alternative calendar that would let me do such a thing?

Comment: If these are separate calendars, then this is a tall order. I do not know of any native Outlook capability for this.

Comment: Yeah, the more I think about it, the more complicated the problem seems to be.

Comment: Re: colleagues seeing your personal calendar, one option that might help if you go that direction is the `Private` option. If you set the appointment to Private in your work calendar, you still see the content, but anyone with access to your work calendar only sees `Private Appointment` so know you're unavailable for meetings, but can't see the content.

Comment: You can merge them to a one celenda: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/merge-items-from-multiple-calendars-0a7b4a55-ea17-4024-bc98-1766d2382780 or Overlay the calendars: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-multiple-calendars-at-the-same-time-fffa8783-0556-4ea1-ba62-3ed8a95a903c

Comment: Why is the [tag:google-calendar] tag included in this question? Google Calendar is not mentioned in the question body.

Comment: The "family calendar" I mention happens to be a Google calendar. The point is that I need to consolidate calendars from different platforms. If they were all in MS Office, that wouldn't be so much a problem.